# Filter DBO schema/owner only - dont show SYS Stored Procedures

Tags: c#, sql, smo, sys, dbo

I am scripting all the Stored Procedures in a Database, via SMO.
It is now returning Stored Procedures from both DBO and SYS owner/schema's

How do I filter it to only show SP's from DBO please:

```
            StringCollection spScripts = AdventureWorks.Script(scriptOptions);
            foreach (StoredProcedure mySP in AdventureWorks.StoredProcedures)
            {
                foreach (string script in spScripts)
                    sw.WriteLine(script);

                /* Generating CREATE TABLE command */
                spScripts = mySP.Script();
                foreach (string script in spScripts)
                    sw.WriteLine(script);
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The StoredProcedure class has a Schema property, you could use this to filter.

```
if (mySP.Schema == "dbo")
```

Not sure right now, if StoredProcedures collection implements the right interfaces, but maybe you can even filter it directly on the StoredProcedures object via LINQ

```
AdventureWorks.StoredProcedures.Where(p => p.Schema == "dbo")
```

Comment: LINQ not supported unfortunately, but if statement the way to go, thanks